# Only username and password (withour certificate and private key)

Tags: python, opc-ua

I am trying to access SINUMERIK (Siemens) OPC UA. The server is only username and password protected (without certificate and private key). I have tried to connect with the following:

```py
client = Client(url)
client.set_user("my_user")
client.set_passwotd("my_password")
client.connect()
```

But I have received a "TimeoutError". I have also tried the following:

```py
client = Client(url)
client.connect_socket()
client.create_session()
client.activate_session(username="my_user", password = "my_password")
```

But it leads to the same timeout error as well.

It is working on UaExpert though. What could be the issue here?

Comment: I have no experience with Siemens and the library you use but connecting to an OPC UA server has more steps than what you use. I think you also need to do **handshake**, **select an endpoint** for which surely before you will have first to list them and also **open secure channel**

Comment: Hey, did you find  a solution?

Comment: I am stuck at the same problem. Please help ,if you found any solution

Comment: You're only showing the user authentication part of the connection process. What security policy do you use?